# How to give fixed height to Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular-material2

I have an `angular material table(10 rows)`for which i want to fix the height to 300px(Vertical scroll should be used to see the extra rows). When i give height in the styles to `300px` it is not having any effect. 
The contents of the table are going out of the height given.

See the link for the image.

I want to have two tables one below another and i want to give them equal `height 50%.` The first table itself taking `10 rows height`.

[Angular Material Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8q2dj.png)

Comment: Can you add html code?

Answer (score 25):

I use a wrapper div with class

```
<div class="table-container">
   <table mat-table [dataSource]=.....>
   </table>
</div>
```

and this is the class

```
.table-container {
  margin-top: 10px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Basically it will work but if you provide padding to the outer class that is wrapper class then the UI would break and the scroll will not be on table but will be on the wrapper div

Comment: Just a note for future readers, max-height needs to be a fixed value (like 300px) versus a percentage (like 80%). In my scenario, I added a media query for height to adjust the fixed value:
`@media only screen and (max-height: 500px) {
    div.limit-table-size {
        max-height: 250px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-height: 500px) and (max-height: 800px) {
    div.limit-table-size {
        max-height: 400px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
}
`

Answer (score -3):

Try this one in css file

```css
table tr.mat-row {
  height: 300px;
}
```